# ExpressionEngine: referencing js file vs script in template

Tags: javascript, php, expressionengine

I have a EE template in which I use a EE global variable {global_var}.
In the same template I have a js script.

```
//opening js script tag
{global_var}
//closing js script tag
```

Inside this script I can read and use {global_var}.
But if I move the script code to a JS template and reference to it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='{path="js/contact_form"}'></script>
```

the {global_var} is no more available, why?

More info: {global_var} is a user defined variable that I added to index.php

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    "base_url" => "http://www.example.com/",
    "global_var" => "hello"
);
```

Is there a way to read EE global variables in the referenced js file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotation mark to the global variable when you're outputting it to the Js.

```
"{global_var}"
```

Another reason why it may not work can be either:

- The variable doesn't exist in the the DB So you might need to use syncSnippert to synchronize between the two.
- The template for the variable doesn't exist so you might need to create it.